# How do I setup a permanent background VPN connection for Ubuntu/ Apache2 server?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, vpn, ubuntu-18.04

We are building PHP backend application on a Ubuntu 18.04 server running Apache 2.4.

The application needs to connect to a secure external server than can only be connected via a VPN. The server is command line via SSH only.

I can setup a VPN via command line like this:

Install OpenConnect:

```
sudo apt install openconnect
```

I'm not 100% sure if this command is necessary:

```
sudo /sbin/modprobe tun
```

And then connect to the VPN using OpenConnect:

```
sudo -b openconnect vpn.example.com
```

To connect I need to enter the following information:

1. Group name (i.e. "Default")
2. Username
3. Password
4. Select text menu option for two-factor authentication  (i.e. "1")

The two-factor authentication goes through an app on my phone.

We need to able to do all of this but have the connection running permanently in the background so the PHP application can connect to the secure server via the VPN.

At the moment even though I'm using the `-b` option the terminal window doesn't return to the command line & gives me no indication the VPN connection will remain if I close the terminal window/ disconnect from the server.

If it helps we're using the following PHP to connect:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://secure-server.example.com/api/');
curl_setopt($ch, etc. etc. etc.)
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This approach works in a local development environment (on Ubuntu 18.04).